# Simplest set of axioms and inference rules for first-order logic?

Tags: first-order-logic, axioms, foundations, formal-proofs, formal-systems

I'm interested in finding the "simplest" formulation of first-order logic. To be precise, what formulation of first-order logic has the fewest total axioms (or axiom schemas, henceforth just called axioms) and inference rules? I'm ok with leaving either $\exists$ or $\forall$ out of the language entirely, since we can define one in terms of the other.

For starters, Appendix C of Robert Wolf's *Tour through Mathematical Logic* contains seven axioms and one inference rule. In fact, one axiom is the definition of $\exists,$ which I'm ok with omitting, so that leaves just six axioms and one inference rule. Can we do even better?

Comment: For propositional logic, [one axiom (and Modus Ponens) is enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems#Classical_propositional_calculus_systems).

Comment: [Enderton](https://www.google.it/books/edition/A_Mathematical_Introduction_to_Logic/dVncCl_EtUkC) adds 3 axioms for the universal quantifier ($\exists$ is defined) and no further rules. Two further axioms if *equality* is needed.

Comment: Another approach is to assume all *tautologies* as axioms and then add only an axiom for quantification and two inference rules: MP and one for the quantifier.